# How to choose the features for an algorithm from the given attached screenshot?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, features

How to choose the features from the given attached heat map & correlation factor for the classification algorithm?

I have 6 different features i.e., ac233fc01403, ac233fc02eaa, ac233fc015f6, ac233fc044aa, ac233fc0455d, ac233fc0451f. From the 6 different features, I should classify in which segment(i.e.,class) the test data is?

How to choose from the given plot, which are the feature has to be considered for the algorithm to achieve the better efficiency?

[image: Heat Map]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing anything about what you're trying to classify, the size of your data, etc. Anyway it's probably a good idea to use all 6 features.

Answer (score 1):

Why start with feature selection/engineering if you have so few features to begin with?

Best practice should be to include all features/variables in your first draft model and look at the accuracy, quality of resulting segments, etc.

If there is need to improve and to leave out a feature you could then use the metrics of variable importance of your chosen model (e.g. variable importance from random forest) to decide which feature was least relevant and could be discarded for a slimmer model.

In general model performance shouldn't suffer to much from including irrelevant features and therefore selection isn't the same issue as it would be for less robust models.